# Why is assignment allowed in C99 array declaration?

Tags: c, arrays, c99

There seem to be weird ways allowed in C99 for declaring array sizes.

```
D[ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]
D[ static type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expression ]
D[type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression]
D[type-qualifier-listopt *]
```

An example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;

int func0(int array[x = 3])
{
    return 1;
}

int func1(int array[(4, x = 3)])
{
    int other_array[x = 4];
    return 1;
}

int func2(int array[printf("this is weird: %d\n", x) && func1(NULL)])
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int array[128];

    func2(array);   //  <-- prints "this is weird: 0\n"
    func2(array);   //  <-- prints "this is weird: 4\n"
}
```

BTW this is not valid C89, and not at all valid C++

I have a lot of questions.

- Are these constructs used anywhere?
- If not, why did implementors bother to implement these, and why wasn't this deprecated in C11?
- What could be the original intent of allowing these?
- What the heck??

Comment: Looks like a natural consequence of the introduction of VLA types. I wouldn't have expected the expressions in the function parameter types to be evaluated, though; I thought they would have been eliminated by the conversion of array types to pointer types in function parameters.

Comment: So, You say VLA types can't be done without allowing assignments? I can understand `int array[x]` , but I too dumb here to see why specifically assignments need to be allowed. Maybe my mind is too simple for this, I just don't really get it.

Comment: If you're going to allow stuff like `int array[i++];` or `int array[calculateLength()];`, there isn't much of a case to ban assignments.